# How to make points with fixed distance and orientation from another points layer?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I have a points layer with hundreds of features at variable distance from each other. Now what I want to do is create 4 new points for each feature of this layer at a fixed distance (30m) AND orientation (exactly North, East, South, West).

Something like this (forgive my draw skills):

[image]

Where grey points are from input and the color ones are the output.

I was willing to do in QGIS, but can be also PostGIS or another solution.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to choose one environment, and show your work toward solving the problem in that environment. Please also specify whether the coordinate reference system is geographic or projected (and which projection). Hint: Do not trust Web Mercator for distance measurement.

Comment: possible duplicate (though I had to parse my answers to find it because that other question is phrased *exceptionally* poor to ask for the same thing): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272942/given-a-lat-long-find-all-points-within-a-certain-radius

Comment: You can use the `geometry by expression` tool to create points based on the answer @ThingumaBob linked to. Or if you just want to visualize those points, use them in a `geometry generator` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired result can be achieved both in QGIS and PostGIS, and I will offer a method in QGIS in SRID 4326.

1) Run the "Rectangles, ovals, rhombus (fixed)" tool and set the values ​​specified in the fields, see figure 1.

[image]

2) Extract from all the obtained rhombuses of the point, for which run Vector> Geometry processing> Extract vertices ... see figure 2.

[image]

3) See the result in figure 3.

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Always welcome, with respect ...